# NSUserDefaults and Update an application from app Store

Tags: iphone, app-store, nsuserdefaults

In my app I'm using NSUserDefaults to store user data, when upgrading to a new version from App Store will those values be saved or deleted/ rebooted?
(for example: `[prefs setInteger:_numberOfTimesAppOpened forKey:@"openApp"];` if before the upgrade the value is 70 after the upgrade will the value be 70/ 0/ or non existent?)

1. in case these parameters are deleted what is the right approach to save user data so it will be saved even when upgrading the application?
2. another question is if there is a way to store information on the device so if the user delete the app and then re-install it his previous data/ profile can be set?

Answer (score 0):

Everything that is stored in UserDefaults will be still there after an update. They are persisting. User defaults will get deleted when the app is removed from the device by the user.

And there is no way to store if an app was installed already once. At least not on the device.